# Our Win8 Metro App crashes after a long time standing

Tags: crash, microsoft-metro, sleep

We are developing a Win8 Metro App with C#2012. After a long time standing or waken up from sleep, the app crashed. Worse still was that none exception can be captured even when it was running in IDE.
Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the metro applications run on different threads so which thread will terminate when is a difficult thing to say still some guide lines from microsoft says that

If the app is suspended for more than 10 seconds then it terminates
and Even an exception in the running thread can abnormally abrupt the process.

Here are few links You can go through to check apps termination

Best advised is to save the application state so that when resumed user could be directed to what they were doing before

Please go through the following links where they explain the same :-

[Suspend and Resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx)

[App life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Anobik! You gave us some good suggestion. To save user's data frequently may be the best choice. Just as our Chinese saying gose， it is the method witch not a real method.

Comment: Your most Welcome and Its My Pleasure :)